# Openshift with nodejs and nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, openshift, openshift-cartridge

### context

I've a running app on Openshift using a nodejs (nodejs-0.10). I would like to add a ngix as first proxy to serve static files only.

### problem

The question is how to add nginx to a running app on Openshift. I saw this cartridge [gsterjov/openshift-nginx-cartridge](https://github.com/gsterjov/openshift-nginx-cartridge) but the README instructs how to create a new app using the nginx, but not how to add it to an existing app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not add a secondary web framework cartridge to an application.  Each application can only have one web framework cartridge installed at a time.  You might need to setup a second application and setup nginx as a proxy if you want the requests to hit that first and serve static assets, then proxy the dynamic requests back to your node.js application.

Comment: thank you @coreydaley, I understand your point. But is that the same to say that it's not possible to have nginx and nodejs in the same application using openshift?

Comment: Yes.  There would not be a way to expose both application at the same time.

Comment: Possibly this modulus.io analogy helps: http://blog.modulus.io/supercharge-your-nodejs-applications-with-nginx